# OPC Publisher 2.8.4 : BadMonitoredItemIdInvalid

Tags: azure, opc-ua, azure-iot-edge, opc, azure-industrial-iot

I'm running OPCPublisher and when I try to get some node's value I get this message: :"StatusCode":{"Symbol":"BadMonitoredItemIdInvalid","Code":2151809024}.
I never had this problems in other servers.

**I use the same nodeId that UaExpert shows:**
[image]

**My file configurations is the following one:**
[image]

**I get this message instead of the node value:**
[{"MessageId":"1","MessageType":"ua-data","PublisherId":"opc.tcp://192.168.xx.xx:xxxx_3182BABF","Messages":[{"DataSetWriterId":"1000","SequenceNumber":1,"MetaDataVersion":{"MajorVersion":1,"MinorVersion":0},"Timestamp":"2023-03-06T10:11:54.503Z","Payload":{"part_counter":{"StatusCode":{"Symbol":"BadMonitoredItemIdInvalid","Code":2151809024}}}}]}]

Answer (score 0):

Is this an error or just a message ? Does the subscription works ?

Is this BadMonitoredItemIdInvalid in the response of a CreateMonitoredItems request ?

BadMonitoredItemIdInvalid should actually only be present in either a Response to a Request of type:

- DeleteMonitoredItems
- ModifyMonitoredItems
- SetMonitoringMode
- SetTriggering

In your case, a Wireshark capture of an unencrypted session will help you solve your issue.